# Perform operation on all Contacts of a dynamic distribution list | Add/remove category keywords

Tags: 2013-sp1, audience-manager

How to perform a common operation on all contacts from a dynamic distribution list?

1 way is to export them in CSV, modify in CSV and upload. But, if I want to remove/add a category/keyword to all contacts, I believe this wouldn't work.

If there's no way to do it via CME, I would go with creating an application using Tridion.AudienceManagement.API.

Please assist.

Using 2013 SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing the Keywords you can choose to overwrite all of the Keywords on the affected Contacts. So if you export the Keywords, remove the ones you don't want from the resulting file, and then import - choosing to overwrite - you would effectively remove the Keyword from all of those Contacts.

As you mention, the other option is to do it in code using the API.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter. I din't know before that we have option of exporting keywords on Contacts, I was just clicking "Export" button and it was not exporting keywords. I will try exporting & importing keywords (from Address book). Thanks for quick response :)